# ipad/iphone scrolling div - scroll bars to appear

Tags: ipad, html, scrollbar

I have a single page app which has scrolling DIVs as part of the UI on our iPhone/iPad app.

In HTML how do I get the div to show a scroll bar to visually indicated to the user that the area can scroll?

Ian

Comment: Just making a comment here so I can return this answer in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobile safari specifically disables scroll bars on overflowing scrollable divs. There is no easy way to enable this without building your own scrollable div visual indicator.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* has to be scroll, not auto */
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!